# PHPMailer include php page as body?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send php page data as body in mail using PhpMailer.

All my code is working properly.

my main page code:

```
<?php
require_once('libs/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
require 'libs/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$some_page_contents =  file_get_contents('welcome.php');  

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->Host     = "smtp.example.com";
$mail->Username = "first@example.com";
$mail->Password = "example";
$mail->SetFrom("first@example.com","first User");
$mail->AddAddress("second@example.com");
$mail->isHtml(true);
$mail->Subject  = "Second PHPMailer Message";
$mail->Body     =  $some_page_contents; 
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->Send();
?>
```

My welcome.php code

```
<?php 
echo 'hello';
```

In the mail I got `<?php echo 'hello';`
Whydo I get the php body in the mail also?

Comment: An email isn't a web page. It is, at best, an HTML page with some limited CSS. You can't send dynamic content, JavaScript, PHP etc - you can only send HTML & CSS or plain text. It will be interpreted by the email client as one of the two.

Comment: Enable `allow_url_fopen` in your php.ini and then do like this to `$some_page_contents =  file_get_contents('http://example.com/welcome.php'); ` in order to actually let php generate the page contents. Right now you are only getting the actual content from the `welcome.php` file, it's not parsed as php

Comment: Base your code on the examples provided with PHPMailer, not random, obsolete things you find.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this many times. I have many applications that need to send templated email. I resolve this by making my templates load a variable. So for example, in my main file, I'll have just an include statement to include the template file. After the include I will set the message body to a designated variable, lets call it $body. But in the actual template file, I will set the body like this.

```
$body = <<<EOF
Hello $name!!
EOF;
```

This way you can run the PHP code in the template file and get a variable in return.

Another way I solve this issue is to just make my templates plaintext but use a placeholder like {name} and the just use a str_replace function to replace all the instances of {name} with the actual variable value.

Neither of these are really an answer but more of alternative. Good luck.